# Webpack theme loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'd like to accomplish the following structure:

- `button.core.jsx`
- `button.theme-a.jsx`
- `button.theme-b.jsx`

To take React as an example, I'd like to do the following in `button.core.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Themed from './button.[theme]';

export default class Button extends React.Component {
    render() {
        if (Themed) {
            return <Themed />;
        }
        return <button>default button</button>;
    }
}
```

In other words, I want to define a theme in my `webpack.config.js` and load that file if it exists. If it does't, render the default behaviour. I think this would be a very powerful setup!

I've been searching around for making a custom loader, but no success yet. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

I've got this working with writing a custom "resolver":

```
const ThemeResolver = {
    apply: function(resolver) {
        resolver.plugin('file', function(req, cb) {
            if (req.request.indexOf('[theme]') == -1) {
                return cb();
            }

            const defaultFile = req.request.replace('[theme]', 'Default');
            const themedFile = req.request.replace('[theme]', process.env.THEME);
            req.request = themedFile;

            this.doResolve(['file'], req, (err) => {
                if (!err) {
                    return cb();
                }
                req.request = defaultFile;
                this.doResolve(['file'], req, cb);
            })
        });
    }
};

module.exports = {
    // ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ResolverPlugin([ThemeResolver]),
    ]
    // ...
};
```

It tries to resolve a file with `[theme]` in its path into a path with the theme defined as a environment variable. If it fails, it'll fallback to a default file instead. This way I can require a themed file like so:

`import Presentation from './button-[theme]'`

The main component turned out to be a bit different than in my question, but I'm actually pretty content with it:

```
import React from 'react';
import Presentation from './button-[theme]';

export default class Button extends React.Component {
    onClick = (e) => console.log('some logic');

    render() {
        return <Presentation onClick={ this.onClick } />;
    }
}
```

The logic of this button-component can live inside of `button.core.jsx`, while the presentation will be handled by one of these components:

```
THEME=theme-a npm start // button-[theme] resolves to button-theme-a.jsx
THEME=theme-c npm start // button-[theme] resolves to button-default.jsx
```

Disclaimer: I didn't use this in a large scale or production environment yet, but it seems to work in a small POC. Please let me know if I'm doing something unwise!

Comment: I ran into one problem with this. Other plugins don't seem to see it. So, in my case, using `html-webpack-plugin` for the favicon, it never resolves the theme tag.

Comment: That would actually make sense, because you're not requiring/importing anything at that point. You're only making a reference and your browser will load the favicon. Can't you add some logic inside your template though?

Comment: That's probably what I will do. Modularize the "does my branded file exist" code above so I can use it outside the resolver.